# Joomla set Temporary PHP directory

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I installed Joomla 3.1.1 Stable on a Centos system.
I can access it, browse through it's admin backend and frontend, but I found in the Extension Manager/Warnings that "The PHP temporary directory is not set"
 I went on google and found a fix: I created a php.ini file where I completed this line:

```
upload_tmp_dir = var/www/html/joomla/tmp
```

I did that because that is the location where I installed joomla (var/www/html/joomla/)
The fix I found online gave some other location for this folder, it was something with the home/accountname/public_html/... , but I do not have joomla installed in any accounts, it is installed in the "public":  var/www/html folder.
I am asking what am I doing wrong because even after doing this, the warning stays the same:

```
"The PHP temporary directory is not set"
```

How can I fix this?
I set up the permissions for the entire joomla folder to 40777, and then to the inner folders and files so I would avoid a permission conflict. I then disabled the FTP from Global Settings (before doing this I was receiving a lot more errors when trying to upload anything)
I seriously thought that installing joomla on Centos would not give me so many headaches.
I need to install an extension in joomla (for a template) and I have an error that says nothing to me:"-1 - An error has occurred." - "Copy file failed" so I try to fix any warnings/errors that may cause this before giving up.

The fixes found online about this error (Copy file failed) refer to joomla 1.5 - 1.6. How is it possible that I still get it in version 3.1 ? It is rather absurd.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Setting the Joomla folder to 777 won't do anything. Even if it did, it is not a solution that should even be considered. Are you sure you have got the path correct? Did you restart apache after making changes to the *php.ini* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working after I changed permissions to ALL subfolders located in var/www/html/joomla

I will reset those permissions after I finish with configuring and customizing the website.
But for now, that was my solution.

```
-di3sel - the upload_tmp_dir was set up correctly in the php.ini
```

Thank you both, but my problem seems to be solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it via .htaccess file, just add this:

```
php_value upload_tmp_dir /var/www/html/joomla/tmp
```